# How to show two functions can not be solutions of a same ODE of the form $y' = F(t,y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question 1: Consider here the two functions $f: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$
and $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(t)=t^2$ and $g(t)=t^2 -t +1$. Show that $f, g$ are not solutions of a same ODE on $\mathbb R$ of the form $y'=F(t,y)$, with $F: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a function.

I know this must be try, but I don't really know how to write a formal proof.
My attempt right now:

Assume that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are both solutions of the same ODE $y' = F(t,y)$. Then $2t = F(t, t^2)$, $2t- 1 = F(t, t^2 -t+1)$ I am kind of lost after this, I also create a plot of this question.

[image]

Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: *Hint:* What can you say about $f'(c)$ and $g'(c)$ if $c=1$ is the point where $f$ and $g$ intersect?

Comment: The slope of the tangent line at c = 1 is not the same?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the contradiction, that both $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are solutions. Then, we have simultaneusly $$2t = F(t, t^2)$$ and $$ 2t = F(t, t^2-t+1) +1 $$

Then we must have that these agree,

$$F(t, t^2) -2t = F(t, t^2-t+1) -2t +1$$
$$F(t, t^2) = F(t, t^2-t+1) +1$$

Let $t=1$ and we have

$$F(1, 1) = F(1, 1) + 1$$

Which is a contradiction. Therefore our initial assumption is not true, and $f(t)$, $g(t)$ are not solutions to the same ODE.

Comment: Thank you for your clear proof!

Answer (score 0):

At $t_0 = 1$ is $ f(t_0) = 1 = g(t_0)$ but $f'(t_0) = 2 \ne 1 = f'(t_0)$.

If $f$ and $g$ were solutions of the same ODE $y'=F(t, y)$ then
$$
 f'(t_0) = F(t_0, f(t_0)) = F(t_0, g(t_0)) = g'(t_0)
$$
is a contradiction, so this is not possible.

*Remark:* This is a very simple case of the general fact that solutions of [“initial value problems”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) are locally unique (under some conditions on the function $F$). If two functions $f$ and $g$ are both solutions of the same ODE with the same initial value $y(t_0) = y_0$ then these functions are identical near $t_0$, that is the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).